# Pandas read CSV, i cannot read Vietnamese text

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFf26.png)
I'm trying to read Vietnamese text, but this is what I've received, something's wrong here, these words are not Vietnamese, can anyone help me to figure it out? Thank you so much!

Comment: Set `encoding='utf-8'` or whatever encoding you need, then retry it and tell us what happens

Comment: please no images and even less links to images. Your question is hard to understand

Answer (score 1):

In `pd.read_csv(..., encoding='utf-8')` or whatever encoding you need.